# DashboardColumn disappears in Dashboard Primefaces

Tags: primefaces

The dashboard doesn't work as expected. There is only panel in 3rd column in my dashboard. When i move it to 2nd Column, then the 3rd column disappears. Then, I am not able to move any other panel into 3rd column

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation

> Provide a column width using ui-dashboard-column style class otherwise empty columns might
>   not receive new widgets.

So use css style to give width to your columns.

```
.ui-dashboard-column {
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Hi hello @Geinmachi its not working i tried this earlier, my code is like as in prime faces demo

Comment: What version of PrimeFaces do you use?

Comment: If it is working in showcase and is not working in your case then you have something wrong, so post the code.

Comment: Hi @Geinmachi  i got it partially now i can place the panel into any of the 3 columns,but its not possible to keep the tabs where i need to places in the 3 columns Y?

Answer (score 1):

In the Primefaces [GitHub](https://github.com/primefaces/showcase/blob/master/src/main/webapp/ui/panel/dashboard.xhtml) you can see this css style in the head part of the xhtml file:

```
.ui-panel, div.ui-state-hover {
    margin: 10px;
    width:200px;
}

.ui-dashboard-column {
    width:220px;
}
```

This css code that replaces the proposed in the answer by @Geinmachi helped me.